# Undefined symbols for architecture while using ELCImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, undefined-symbol, elcimagepickercontroller

I am using ELCImagePicker library to multi selection of images but getting below error.How should i solve?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ELCImagePickerController", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for ObjectiveC.ELCImagePickerController in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)